# Fill Javascript object with fixed length multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multidimensional-array, fill

I am trying to wrap my head around javascript objects and arrays. I attempted to fill and access an object as following:

```
obj_keys = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
o = {};

$.each(obj_keys, function(k, v){
    o[v] = [];
    for(var c; c < 10; c++){
        o[v][c] = [];
        o[v][c].push([11,12,13,14]);
    }
});

console.log(o);
```

Object { 1: Array[10], 2: Array[10], 3: Array[10], 4: Array[10], 5: Array[10], 6: Array[10], 7: Array[10] }

```
console.log(o[7]);
```

Array [ ]

```
console.log(o[7][8]);
```

undefined

```
console.log(o[7][8][3]);
```

TypeError: o[7][8] is undefined

Why **o[v] = [ ];** is OK, yet **o[v][c] = [ ];** in my for(;;) loop is not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> for(var c; c < 10; c++){
> ```

is your problem. You don't initialise `c`, so it is `undefined`, or later `NaN`, and those are used as property names for adding your arrays onto `o[v]`. Use instead:

```
for(var c = 0; c < 10; c++){
```

Comment: Bonus question:  `console.log(o[7][8][3]);` returns `undefined`, how do I access it?

Comment: Nevermind, it should be `console.log(o[7][8][0][3]);`